# Function calls in hash come up empty in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I've been sifting through the prior questions and answers on stackoverflow, and I have gotten most of my question figured out.  I figured out that I can't place a function call within a hash, without placing it within a proc, or a similar container.

What I'm ultimately trying to do is have a menu displayed, grab user input, and then iterate through the hash, and run the specified function:

```
def Main()
    menu_titles = {"Answer1" => Proc.new{Choice1()}}
    Menu(menu_titles)
end

def Choice1()
    puts "Response answer"
end

def Menu(menu_titles)
   menu_titles.each_with_index do |(key, value),index|
        puts "#{index+1}. #{key}"
   end 

user_input = 0 

   menu_titles.each_with_index do |(key, value), index|
        if index.eql?(user_input)
           menu_titles[value]
           break
        end 
   end 
end

Main()
```

The issue I'm having right now is that I'm not entering the functions that my hash calls for.  Whether I use a return or a "puts", I either get a blank line or nothing at all.  If anyone has other recommendations about my code, I'm all ears also.  To be honest, I don't like using procs, but that's mostly because I don't entirely know how they work and where to use them.

Right now for my menus I have:

```
user_input = 1
if user_input == 1
   Choice1()
...
end
```

Comment: This code needs a complete refactoring, you may have better luck at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. First, try using `name_with_underscore` methods, otherwise it does not even look like Ruby :-)

Comment: Other than my mixed up variables, am I headed in the right direction, or would it simply be easier to delete it all and start anew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would refactor this:

```
class Menu
  attr_reader :titles

  # initialize sets up a hard-coded titles instance variable,
  # but it could easily take an argument.
  def initialize 
    @titles = { 
      "Answer1" => Proc.new{ puts "choice 1" },
      "Answer2" => Proc.new{ puts "choice 2" } 
    }
  end

  # This is the only public instance method in your class,
  # which should give some idea about what the class is for
  # to whoever reads your code
  def choose
    proc_for_index(display_for_choice)
  end

  private

    # returns the index of the proc.
    def display_for_choice
      titles.each_with_index { |(key,value), index| puts "#{index + 1}. #{key}" }
      gets.chomp.to_i - 1 # gets will return the string value of user input (try it in IRB)
    end 

    # first finds the key for the selected index, then 
    # performs the hash lookup.
    def proc_for_index(index)
      titles[titles.keys[index]]
    end
end
```

If you're serious about Ruby (or object-oriented programming in general), I would highly recommend learning about the advantages of packaging your code into behavior-specific classes. This example allows you to do this:

```
menu = Menu.new
proc = menu.choose
#=> 1. Answer1
#=> 2. Answer2
2 #(user input)

proc.call
#=> choice 2
```

And you could actually run it on one line:

```
Menu.new.choose.call
```